# How is it possible to implement cypher transformation RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-512AndMGF1Padding for signing with private key in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, bouncycastle

The module node-forge gets close but doesn't allow signing with private key.

Comment: "encryption with private key" is called signing.

Comment: Both `node-forge` and node.js builtin `crypto` can sign with RSA private key (and verify with public key) -- but not with OAEP, because OAEP is encryption-only (Optimal Asymmetric _Encryption_ Padding). There is a technically similar RSA signature method, also using MGF1 but not in the same way, called PSS (Probabilistic Signature Scheme), again implemented by both `node-forge` (didn't check history) and `crypto` since v8. Java, the only thing that uses 3-part 'transform' names like that, also can OAEP encrypt (using public) but not sign (using private).